# Ignore field from bindingResult validation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.1.3 (Embedded Tomcat)` + `Thymeleaf 3` + `java 8`. I have a problem regarding validation of a `UserDTO` that is similar to follow:

```
@Data
public class UserDTO {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String surname;
    .....
    @NotBlank
    @Email
    @UniqueEmailConstraint   // this is a custom validator
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String pass;
    .......
}
```

`@UniqueEmailConstraint` check inside the DB if the email is present or not (just one email for account are admitted). Than I have 2 controller, one for inserting user and another one for updating user

```
@PostMapping("/save-user")
String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("userDTO") @Valid UserDto userDto, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "fragment/form-user";
    }
```

and similar one with some other function:

```
@PostMapping("/update-user")
String updateUser(@ModelAttribute("userDTO") @Valid UserDto userDto, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "fragment/form-user";
    }
```

The problem is that when I selecting a user to modify it, a thymeleaf view is open and show me all data inserted as expected (mail included). If I try to modify another field, for example `Address` and click submit my controller show an errors because it find the email on DB.

Question is, is there a way to ignore certain field on `bindingResult`? Because of I would like to ignore the `@UniqueMailConstraint` error on second controller Validation.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar problem hope this helps:
Let's say there is an employee HTML form with two buttons:
One of the buttons should validate the whole form, while the other button should validate just one single field and ignore the validation for the rest.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "saveEmployee", params = "action=save")
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") EmployeeDTO employee, BindingResult bindingResult, final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    //Create a new BindingResult with zero errors
    BindingResult newBindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(employee, "employee");
    
    //Add to the new BindingResult the error which is caused by the field 'employeeNumber'
    newBindingResult.addError(bindingResult.getFieldError("employeeNumber"));
    //If required, more fields can be added to the new BindingResult
    
    //Check if the new BindingResult contains errors -> only the fields added above.
    if (newBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        //Do this, if the new BindingResult contains validation errors
    } else {
        //Do that, if the new BindingResult does not contain errors validation errors
        //If your form contains other validation errors for fields other than 'employeeNumber', the validation for them will be ignored.
    }

    //Set the view and return it.
    mav.setViewName("your_html_page");
    return mav;
}
```